# XJC episode with maven

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, cxf, xjc

How can I generate an episode with maven? I now get an error message: `an operand is missing (org.apache.cxf:cxf-xjc-plugin:2.4.0:xsdtojava:generate-sources:generate-sources)`

Here my plugin:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-xjc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <extensions>
                    <extension>org.apache.cxf.xjcplugins:cxf-xjc-dv:2.4.0</extension>
                </extensions>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xsdtojava</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <xsdOptions>
                            <xsdOption>
                                <extension>true</extension>
                                <xsd>my.xsd</xsd>
                                <packagename>mypackage</packagename>
                                 <extensionArgs>
                                  <arg>-episode</arg>
                                 </extensionArgs>
                            </xsdOption>
                        </xsdOptions>
                    </configuration>

                </execution>
                <execution>
                 <configuration>
                        <xsdOptions>
                 <xsdOption>
                        <extension>true</extension>
                          <xsd>my.xsd</xsd>
                        <extensionArgs>
                            <arg>-Xdv</arg>
                        </extensionArgs>
                    </xsdOption>
                        </xsdOptions>
                    </configuration>

                </execution>


            </executions>
```

**Edit:** Creation of the episode works fine. In another project the jar file containing the episode is given in though the `episodes` attribute. But I get an Exception: `Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ file:/D:/workspace/XXX/src/test/resources/XXX.xsd{45,32}]. om.sun.istack.SAXParseException2: compiler was unable to honor this conversion customization. It is attached to a wrong place, or its inconsistent with other bindings. nested in com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2: (the above customization is attached to the following location in the schema)`

Which is the xsd with episode info that will be included in the final product. Its some xjc:javaType adapter reference on that line. Can that cause problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different plugin from what you're using, but below snipped used to work for me few years back. You might want to see if more recent version of plugin is available etc. Also tweak to use your schema and remove bindings customization if not needed.

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/xsd</schemaDirectory>
      <schemaIncludes>
        <schemaInclude>Core.xsd</schemaInclude>
      </schemaIncludes>
      <bindingDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/xjb</bindingDirectory>
      <bindingIncludes>
        <bindingInclude>JaxbBindings.xjb</bindingInclude>
      </bindingIncludes>
      <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jaxb</generateDirectory>
      <episode>true</episode>
      <episodeFile>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jaxb/META-INF/sun-jaxb.episode</episodeFile>
      <verbose>true</verbose>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.10</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.10</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks this already worked, but now I'm running in to issues while using the episode. Mybe any ideas on that? see edit.

Comment: As far as I recall in order to consume jar with episode you just need to pass it to wsimport or xjc, there should be no extra params needed. I'm confusing why you're have references to 'file:/D:/workspace' in error stack. Do you have references to schema located there somewhere in your files? Standard way would be to package schema inside your jar and reference it from classpath

Comment: I've got a library with xsd and a project with another xsd using elements from the library xsd. These are two different projects. The final product project unpacks the xsd from the jar for final shipment to the production system. The final product xsd refers to the library xsd, that's why there is a relative reference, the stack trace just prints the absolut paths. Removing the `xjc:javaType` annotation solved the problem, but this is still a weird problem. In my final product pom I pass in the dependancy for the library, because otherwise the episode isn't considered and lib code is created

Comment: I've got the feeling that the xjc:javaType information is somehow not saved in the episode? This would explain why the xjc compiler thinks that already existing code and the unpacked jar are somehow different. But this is only a suspicion because I absolutly have no idea how episodes work.