# common xsd schema imported into another schema not being unmarshalled

Tags: schema, unmarshalling, jaxb2

re http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/12/reusing-generated-jaxb-classes.html

I am trying to switch from using castor to jaxb.

I am importing a commontypes.xsd schema into another schema and then using jaxb to generate the java classes but when I unmarhsal a sample XML file the imported types are null unless I explicitly set all the namespaces in the sample xml.

This is a real pain because I want calling apps to be able to send me plain XML not one littered with a tonne of namespaces and prefixes etc.

Any suggestions as to how to avoid having to do this?

I generated .episodes files in maven using the above article and [XJC episode with maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9928518/xjc-episode-with-maven) but it doesnt help and Im still getting nulls when I unmarshal.

Can anyone help?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working!

The problem was the package-info.java file generated by xjc from my .xsd file had elementFormDefault set to be QUALIFIED

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://www.example.com/commontypes", 
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED
)
package com.example.commontypes;
```

When I changed this to be unqualified and recompiled the java code, the unmarshall then worked.

The root cause fix was in my .xsd file, where I set elementFormDefault="unqualified"

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"   
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/commontypes"     
    xmlns="http://www.example.com/commontypes"  
    elementFormDefault="unqualified" 
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
```

This resulting in the following generated package-info.java file

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://www.example.com/commontypes"
)
package com.example.commontypes;
```

and again, the unmarshall then worked!

Thanks to Blaise for all the work he puts in, it was comment on one of his blog posts that let me figure it out!